# viewer.model.getpropertySet using filter for Categories

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

When using getpropertySet we can use the option with propFilter.
I see that propFilter is used to filter NAME of property.
It is possible used to filter in CATEGORY of property ?

[getPropertySet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/shoiF.png)

Answer (score 1):

The filter applies for name and externalId, as mentioned by the [documentation](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/viewer/v7/reference/Viewing/Model/#getpropertyset-dbids-options).

You can retrieve the desired category through iteration:

```
viewer.model.getPropertySet(dbIds, onSuccessCallback, onErrorCallback);

function onSuccessCallback(propertySet){
  let filteredByCategory = {};
  propertySet.forEach((key, properties) => {
    if(key.includes('displayCategory'))
      filteredByCategory[key] = properties;
    }
  });
}
```